# Manually Populating and Selecting ComboBox Items

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datasource

I can't believe how difficult this simple task is.

I have the following code:

```
cboCountry.ValueMember = "ID";
cboCountry.DisplayMember = "Title";
var countries = from c in context.Set<sc_Countries>()
                orderby c.Title
                select new { c.ID, c.Title };
```

Now, I want to populate the ComboBox `cboCountry` with this collection, and then I want to select the list item with the ID (value) "US".

I was able to add the items to the ComboBox using `cboCountry.Items.AddRange(countries.ToList())`, but then `cboCountry.SelectedValue = "US"` had no effect.

Next, I tried adding the collection using `cboCountry.DataSource = countries` but this just left the control list empty.

Surely there must be a simple way to accomplish this trivial task. Can anyone offer the missing ingredient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you call `ToList()` on your `LINQ` statement, you're not actually getting data from the database:

```
var countries = (from c in context.Set<sc_Countries>()
                 orderby c.Title
                 select new { c.ID, c.Title }).ToList();
```

Now you should be able to set the `DataSource`, etc. like you were:

```
cboCountry.ValueMember = "ID";
cboCountry.DisplayMember = "Title";
cboCountry.DataSource = countries;
cboCountry.SelectedValue = "US"
```

---

Edit:

Now that I'm re-reading your question, it looks like you were already calling `countries.ToList()`, but using `Items.AddRange`. I see the same thing you do when I try it.  It appears you have to set the `DataSource` instead of using `Items.AddRange`, for `SelectedValue` to work.

Comment: Yes, this works! Thanks. I was using `ToList()` but just with `AddRange()`. That worked but I couldn't set `SelectedValue`. Also, I'm used to DropDownList in ASP.NET, which doesn't require the data source to be in a list. But with ComboBox it does. I'm up and running. Thanks again.